# Sonatype Nexus 3 content selector by docker container name?

Tags: docker, containers, sonatype, nexus3, jexl

I can't seem to find the documentation on how to set a content selector by a docker container name.

I tried to find all containers that have "_api" in the name:

```
format == "docker" and name =~ "_api"
```

which does not seem to work
I also tried:

```
format == "docker" and path =~ "_api"
```

which does not seem to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for this is:

```
format == "docker" and path =~ ".*_api.*"
```

still I'd like to know which fields I can query from.

Comment: Yep... [Documentation on this subject](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/configuration/repository-management#RepositoryManagement-ContentSelectors) is practically nonexistent as of now... Only details the Maven2 coordinates...